# How to stop CakePHP from interpreting js and css as php

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Here is the problem I am currently facing:

All the js and css files in cakephp's webroot executes php.

There are some js files I use that have `<? and ?>` strings in them.

This causes the file to throw a php exception.

In addition, I think it is bad practice for security to allow this.

I would like to keep all php functionality out of the webroot.

Even if I do a normal include for a file in the webroot, php gets executed.

Does anyone know how to disable this?

I don't mind hacking the core files to fix this issue if I have to.

Would be greatful if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: The comments on this issue might be helpful: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/2316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer myself.

It is in lib/Cake/Routing/Filter/AssetDispatcher.php

In the function _deliverAsset near line 160

```
if ($ext === 'css' || $ext === 'js') {
```

To fix it I changed it to:

```
if(false){
```

Problem solved

Comment: Unfortunately this "problem" exists for some long time already, it's an undocumented, and if you ask me kinda dangerous feature. Personally I'd like to see this either removed or being configurable. See also https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/4057-feature-proposal-remove-or-make-asset-parsing-configurable

Comment: I agree, at least it is easy to fix if you know where to look.

Comment: Just put a copy of AssetDispatcher in you app/lib/Routing/Filter dir with the modified code and it is fixed. The biggest issue is that I think very few people are aware of this feature and can get into some serious trouble if they allow clients to upload js or css files.